# Line Following Robot

Tags: arduino-uno

[image]I have written a code and it works OK with the robot on straight, curved, intersections.   But the robot just moves forward in the current direction whenever it comes across an acute angle turn. I am attaching the code in the description ....can anyone please guide me through the necessary changes or the troubleshoot procedures?

```
#define left_pwm 6
#define right_pwm 3
#define left_1 5
#define left_2 7
#define right_1 4
#define right_2 2
const int ledPin1 = 9;

int left1;
int left2;
int left3;
int left4;
int right1;
int right2;
int right3;
int right4;
int lc=1;
int sc=0;

float Kp=120, Kd=130;   
float error=0, P=0, D=0, PID_value=0;
float initial_motor_speed_l=100;  
float initial_motor_speed_r=100;  
float left_motor_speed=0, right_motor_speed=0;
float previous_error=0;

int left=0;
int right=0;

void setup()
{

  pinMode(A0,INPUT);
  pinMode(A1,INPUT);
  pinMode(A2,INPUT);
  pinMode(A3,INPUT);
  pinMode(A4,INPUT);
  pinMode(A5,INPUT);
  pinMode(11,INPUT);
  pinMode(10,INPUT);

  pinMode(right_pwm,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(right_1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(right_2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(left_1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(left_2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(left_pwm,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin1,OUTPUT);

}
void loop()
{
    line_follow();
 if (right4==lc && left==lc)
 {
  brake();
 } 
 else {
  forward();
 }

    if(right3==lc && left3==lc)
  {
    digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
  }
   else
  {
    digitalWrite(9,LOW);
  }
}
void pid()
{   
    if((left1==lc)&&(right1==lc))   
   {   
    error=0;   
   }
   else if(right1==lc)          
   {   
    error=0.5; 
   }
   else if((right1==lc)&&(right2==lc))  
   {   
    error=1;   
   }
   else if(right2==lc)          
   {   
    error=1.5; 
   }
   else if((right2==lc)&&(right3==lc))  
   {   
    error=2;   
   }
   else if(right3==lc)      
   {   
    error=2.5; 
   }
   else if((right3==lc)&&(right4==lc))  
   {   
    error=3;
   }
   else if(right4==lc)          
   {   
    error=3.5; 
   }
   else if(left1==lc)           
   {   
    error=-0.5;
   }
   else if((left1==lc)&&(left2==lc))  
   {   
    error=-1;  
   }
   else if(left2==lc)       
   {   
    error=-1.5;
   }
   else if((left2==lc)&&(left3==lc))  
   {   
    error=-2;  
   }
   else if(left3==lc)       
   {   
    error=-2.5;
   }
   else if((left3==lc)&&(left4==lc))   
   {   
    error=-3;
   }
   else if(left4==lc)   
   {   
    error=-3.5; 
   }

   P = error;
   D = previous_error-error;
   PID_value = (Kp*P) + (Kd*D);
   previous_error=error;
   left_motor_speed = initial_motor_speed_l+PID_value;
   right_motor_speed = initial_motor_speed_r-PID_value;
   if(left_motor_speed>=255)   
   {    
    left_motor_speed=255;
   }
   if(left_motor_speed<=0)
   {    
    left_motor_speed=0;
   }
   if(right_motor_speed>=255)
   {
    right_motor_speed=255;
   }
   if(right_motor_speed<=0)
   {
    right_motor_speed=0;
   }
   analogWrite(left_pwm, left_motor_speed);
   analogWrite(right_pwm, right_motor_speed);
   digitalWrite(left_1,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(left_2,LOW);
   digitalWrite(right_1,LOW);
   digitalWrite(right_2,HIGH);
}
void line_follow()
{
    left4=digitalRead(A0); 
    left3=digitalRead(A1); 
    left2=digitalRead(A2); 
    left1=digitalRead(11); 
    right1=digitalRead(10); 
    right2=digitalRead(A3); 
    right3=digitalRead(A4); 
    right4=digitalRead(A5); 

    if(left4!=0)   
    {
     left=0;
    }
    if(right4!=0)
    {
     right=0;
    }
    if((left4==0)&&(left3==0)&&(left2==0)&&(left1==0)&&(right1==0)&&(right2==0)&&(right3==0)&&(right4==0))
    {
      if((left>150)&&(right<150))  
      {
            left1=digitalRead(11); 
          right1=digitalRead(10); 
          while((right1==0)&&(left1==0))
      {
        right_turn();
        left1=digitalRead(11); 
            right1=digitalRead(10); 
       }

      }
      else if((left<150)&&(right>150)) 
      {
            left1=digitalRead(11); 
            right1=digitalRead(10); 

            while((left1==0)&&(right1==0))
        {
         left_turn();
         left1=digitalRead(11); 
             right1=digitalRead(10); 
            }
          }
        }
     pid();
     left=left+1;
     right=right+1;
     if(left>20000)
     {
       left=1000;
     }
     if(right>20000)
     {
       right=1000;
     }

}
void right_turn()
{
   analogWrite(left_pwm,75);
   analogWrite(right_pwm,75);
   digitalWrite(left_1,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(left_2,LOW);
   digitalWrite(right_1,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(right_2,LOW);
}
void left_turn()
{
   analogWrite(left_pwm,75);
   analogWrite(right_pwm,75);
   digitalWrite(left_1,LOW);
   digitalWrite(left_2,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(right_1,LOW);
   digitalWrite(right_2,HIGH);
}   
void brake()
{
   analogWrite(left_pwm, 0);
   analogWrite(right_pwm, 0);
   digitalWrite(left_1,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(left_2,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(right_1,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(right_2,HIGH);
}
void forward()
{
   analogWrite(left_pwm,100);
   analogWrite(right_pwm,100);
   digitalWrite(left_1,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(left_2,LOW);
   digitalWrite(right_1,LOW);
   digitalWrite(right_2,HIGH);
}
```

Comment: Does it detect the line at all? You may blink an LED or send debug messages (bluetooth/serial?) to indicate that the sharp turn has been seen. Or is it a software error?

Comment: Just a small comment: did you really use 8 int variables for booleans? Moreover please describe more what is this setup... What are the sensors, how are they placed, what is the control technique?

Comment: @Paul it doesn't detect the acute turn lines , rest all the lines are detected by it perfectly. I suspect its a calibration and software error but I have no idea how to fix it ..can you please guide me through.

Comment: @frarugi87 the sensor used is a 8 sensor line following array clubbed with two 500 rpm medium torque motors. I have  used tb6612fng as the motor driver and Arduino uno as the microcontroller. I am attaching the picture of my robot in the description.

Comment: @frarugi87 the  6 out of 8 int variables read analog values not digital values . So basically only two of the int variables return Booleans.

Comment: @SomitSinha the left# and right# variables are only modified with a digitalRead, so they are either HIGH or LOW..

Answer (score 1):

There are some lines in `pid()` that will never be called.

```
else if (right2 == lc)
{
    error = 1.5;
}
else if ((right2 == lc) && (right3 == lc))
{
    error = 2;
}
```

if `right2 == lc` then the second `else if` will never be called.

You need to refactor this function, its horrid.  Firstly the right and left values for error only differ in sign, so you could right a function that took 4 values in and returned an absolute number.  If you called it for left then make the result negative.  Something like this is actually better, but will prevent the error you had.

```
else if (right3 == lc)
{
      if (right4 == lc)
        error = 3.0;
      else
        error = 2.5;
}
else if (right4 == lc)
{
      error = 3.5;
}
```